# Why doesn't work xml in module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

> AutoAddtocart/BundleAddtocart/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace AutoAddtocart\Bundlemod\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }

}
```

> AutoAddtocart/BundleAddtocart/Block/Addtocartauto.php

```
<?php

namespace AutoAddtocart\BundleAddtocart\Block;

die('sss');

class Addtocartauto extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,

    )
    {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


}
```

> AutoAddtocart/BundleAddtocart/view/frontend/layout/bundleaddtocart_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Automatic Add bundle product to cart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="AutoAddtocart\BundleAddtocart\Block\Addtocartauto" name="bundletocart" template="AutoAddtocart_BundleAddtocart::add_automatic.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> AutoAddtocart\Bundlemod\view\frontend\templates\add_automatic.phtml;

but when I add it to theme page layouts it works

Comment: I hope you paste the full code of `AutoAddtocart/BundleAddtocart/view/frontend/layout/bundleaddtocart_index_index.xml`

Comment: Please state what you're trying and what doesn't work and the question doesn't contain much information.

Comment: When I call the block on the theme designdesign/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml it works

Comment: but I want it to work using the module layout

Comment: I changed bundleaddtocart_index_index.xml to  default.xml and it works now , thanks

Comment: there is a `die()` in your code

Comment: i know , but the code did not reach it, I already solved it by changing bundle_add_cart_index_index to default.xml